# Global Assignment, Parallelism, and foreach

Tags: r, foreach, environment

I have just finished running a long running analysis (24+ hours) on multiple sets of data. Since I'm lazy and didnt want to deal with multiple `R` sessions and pulling the results together afterwards, I ran them in parallel using `foreach`.

The analysis returns an environment full of the results (and intermediate objects), so I attempted to assign the results to global environments, only to find that this didn't work. Here's some code to illustrate:

```
library(doMC)
library(foreach)
registerDoMC(3)

bigAnalysis <- function(matr) {
  results <- new.env()
  results$num1 <- 1
  results$m <- matrix(1:9, 3, 3)
  results$l <- list(1, list(3,4))

  return(results)
}

a <- new.env()
b <- new.env()
c <- new.env()

foreach(i = 1:3) %dopar% {
  if (i == 1) {
    a <<- bigAnalysis(data1)
    plot(a$m[,1], a$m[,2]) # assignment has worked here
  } else if (i == 2) {
    b <<- bigAnalysis(data2)
  } else {
    c <<- bigAnalysis(data3)
  }
}

# Nothing stored :(
ls(envir=a)
# character(0)
```

I've used global assignment within `foreach` before (within a function) to populate matrices I'd set up beforehand with data (where I couldn't do it nicely with `.combine`), so I thought this would work.

**EDIT:** It appears that this only works within the body of a function:

```
f <- function() {
  foreach(i = 1:3) %dopar% {
    if (i == 1) {
      a <<- bigAnalysis(data1)
    } else if (i == 2) {
      b <<- bigAnalysis(data2)
    } else {
      c <<- bigAnalysis(data3)
    }
  }
  d <- new.env()
  d$a <- a
  d$b <- b
  d$c <- c
  return(d)
}
```

Why does this work in a function, but not in the top-level environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your attempts to assign to global variables in the `foreach` loop are failing because they are happening on the worker processes that were forked by `mclapply`.  Those variables aren't sent back to the master process, so they are lost.

You could try something like this:

```
r <- foreach(i = 1:3) %dopar% {
  if (i == 1) {
    bigAnalysis(data1)
  } else if (i == 2) {
    bigAnalysis(data2)
  } else {
    bigAnalysis(data3)
  }
}

a <- r[[1]]
b <- r[[2]]
c <- r[[3]]
ls(a)
```

This uses the default combine function which returns the three environment objects in a list.

Executing the `foreach` loop in a function isn't going to make it work.  However, the assignments would work if you didn't call `registerDoMC` so that you were actually running sequentially.  In that case you really are making assignments to the master process's global environment.

Comment: Thanks! You're right, wrapping it in a function didn't work. Not sure why I thought it did.
Sadly while your approach is correct (i inevitably fell back on `.combine`) `mcapply` gave me a cryptic error message about long vectors not being supported (I guess due to my object sizes) so I'll save them to disk from the `foreach` loop.