# Assign function output with assign

Tags: r, eval, assign

I am using

```
library(foreach)
library(doSNOW)
```

And I have a function `mystoploss(data,n=14)`

I then call it like that `(I want to loop over n=14 for now)`:

```
registerDoSNOW(makeCluster(4, type = "SOCK"))

foreach(i = 14) %dopar% {assign(paste("Performance",i,sep=""),
mystoploss(data=mydata,n=i))}
```

I then try to find `Performance14` from above, `but it is not assigned`.

Is there some way to assign so the output will be in `Performance14`?

And if I use

```
foreach(i = 14) %dopar% {assign(paste("Performance",i,sep=""),
    mystoploss(data=mydata,n=i),envir = .GlobalEnv)}
```

I get error :

```
Error in e$fun(obj, substitute(ex), parent.frame(), e$data) : 
  worker initialization failed: Error in as.name
```

Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the assign operations are happening in the worker processes. The vaues of the variables are being sent back (see your R session console) but not with the names you assigned. You need to capture these values and assign them names again. See this related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18763376/global-assignment-parallelism-and-foreach).

The following is an alternative that may be of help: asign the output of foreach to an intermediate variable and assign it to your desired variables in the current 'master process' environment.

```
PerformanceAll <- foreach(i = 1:14,.combine="c") %dopar% { mystoploss(data=mydata,n=i) } #pick .combine appropriately
for(i in 1:14){ assign(paste("Performance",i,sep=""), PerformanceAll[i]) }
```

Here is the full example I tried:

```
library(foreach)
library(doSNOW)
mystoploss <- function(data=1,n=1){
  return(runif(data)) #some operation, returns a scalar
}
mydata <- 1
registerDoSNOW(makeCluster(4, type = "SOCK"))
PerformanceAll <- foreach(i = 1:14,.combine="c") %dopar% { mystoploss(data=mydata,n=i) }#pick .combine appropriately
for(i in 1:14){ assign(paste("Performance",i,sep=""), PerformanceAll[i]) }
```

---

*Edit*: If the output of `mystoploss` is a list, then do the following changes:

```
mystoploss <- function(data=1,n=1){#Example
  return(list(a=runif(data),b=1)) #some operation, return a list
}
PerformanceAll <- foreach(i = 1:14) %dopar% { mystoploss(data=mydata,n=i) }#remove .combine
for(i in 1:14){ assign(paste("Performance",i,sep=""), PerformanceAll[[i]]) } #double brackets
```

Comment: Ok! My function returns a list so I would like to combine my results so the output is a nested list.

Comment: In that case, leave the .combine option out (the default behaviour here is that foreach %dopar% returns a list for each value of `i`). PerformanceAll will be a list of lists.

Comment: Great! Did not know that I could assign directly to an object with foreach, `PerformanceAll <- foreach(...`, like I mean you can't assign like that with a `for-loop`. Thanks for the help!