# %do% and %dopar% and environment variables

Tags: r, foreach, environment-variables, parallel-foreach

I have noticed a different behaviour using `%do%` and `%dopar%` concerning the management of the variables. Here is a MWE to show what I mean

```
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)
library(iterators)

a = 1
foreach(icount(10)) %do% {a = a + 1}
print(a)
# [1] 11

registerDoParallel(cores = 1)
a = 1
foreach(icount(10)) %dopar% {a = a + 1}
print(a)
# [1] 1
```

In the first case `a` is incremented while in the second one the loop takes a copy and `a` does not change. I was expected the second behaviour with `%dopar%` to apply also with `%do%`. Is there a way to enforce that without using `%dopar%` (because I'm using nested `foreach`loops as in the `foreach` vignette).

Comment: it's an iterator (see iterators package or foreach vignette). It's the same as `foreach(i=c(1:10))`

Comment: you get `2` as a result of the calculation into the loop. But the variable `a` does not change

Comment: Maybe the the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18763376/global-assignment-parallelism-and-foreach) could help

Comment: And maybe another [related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34653567/doparallel-foreach-inconsistently-inherits-objects-from-parent-environment-e#comment57059883_34653567)

Comment: Why do you need this? Usually you should use the return value of the `foreach` loop.

Comment: You can wrap your code in `local`.

Comment: @Roland indeed my problem is like having an `apply` into a `for` loop for some varying criteria. From the foreach vignette I got a way to create a parallel `apply` using two nested `foreach` loops.